# Need an event handler to work on a dynamically added control which interacts with another dynamically added control

Tags: c#, dynamic, datagridview, controls

I need a dynamically added label with a click event to add a row to a dynamically added datagridview. I know how to get an event handler to work with a dynamically added label but I am not sure how to get it to work with the datagridview as well.

I have tried adding a datagridview parameter to the event handler but this is not working for me.

Code to create datagridview and link labels.

```
foreach (DataRow rows in dtbl.Rows)
            {

                // Create Datagridview
                DataGridView datagridview = new DataGridView();

                // Create link labels
                LinkLabel linkLabel = new LinkLabel();

                // Add event handler to the link labels
                linkLabel.Click += new EventHandler(this.linkLabel_Click); 

                this.Controls.Add(datagridview);
                this.Controls.Add(linkLabel);
            }

// Event handler 

  private void linkLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // This doesnt work because "datagridview" doesnt exist, but I just have no idea how to get this to interact with the dynamically created datagridviews.


            int rowIndex = datagridview.Rows.Add();
            DataGridViewRow row = datagridview.Rows[rowIndex];
            row.Cells[0].Value = "5";
            datagridview.CurrentCell = row.Cells[0];
        }


I expect each link label to add a new row to the datagridview it was created with in the for loop. But I just don't how to code it.
```

Comment: Well you have created the datagridview in private scope and its not available in the event handler. Declare a variable at class level and then you can use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `foreach` loop where you create the `LinkLabel` and `DataGridView`, you can assign a reference of the `DataGridView` to `LinkLabel` -- Assuming you are doing this in Windows Form or WPF, you can make use of the control's `Tag` property:

```
linkLabel.Tag = datagridView;
```

Then, in your click event, get the reference:

```
LinkLabel linkLabel = (LinkLabel)sender;
DataGridView datagridView = (DataGridView)linkLabel.Tag;
```